# Reload de página com Jquery sem cache (Chrome)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Na verdade não sei se o problema é o cache ou o script que fiz ou no server que estou usando, mas vamos lá.

Estou usando este código para carregar um documento para o servidor(ainda não avaliei questões de segurança e desempenho).

```js
if($("#add-doc").isValid()){

$.ajax({
    url: 'api/upload-doc.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: formData,
 beforeSend: function(){

  $("#docs-objeto3 #forms").hide();
  $("#docs-objeto3 #loader-bar").show().fadeIn('slow');

 },
 success: function (data) {
  console.log(data);
 },
 cache: false,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false
 xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
              
  var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
              
  if (myXhr.upload) { // Avalia se tem suporte a propriedade upload
  myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {
       if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                 
    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;

    var porcentagem = percentComplete * 100;

    console.log(parseInt(porcentagem)+'%');

    $('#docs-objeto3 #loader-bar .loadbar-label').text(parseInt(porcentagem)+'%');
    $('#docs-objeto3 #loader-bar .progress-bar').width(parseInt(porcentagem)+'%');

    if(porcentagem == 100){
                  
     // window.location.reload(true);
     location.reload(true);
     // document.location.href = 'detalhe-objeto.php?objeto_id='+objeto_id+'&rt=success';
     // $(location).attr('href', 'detalhe-objeto.php?objeto_id='+objeto_id+'&rt=success')

    }

   }
  }, false);
 }
 return myXhr;

 },
 close: function(){

  $("#docs-objeto3 #forms").show();
  $("#docs-objeto3 #loader-bar").hide();

 }
});

}
```

Note que estou usando o método `location.reload(true);` que no Firefox funciona perfeitamente, localmente funciona no Chrome e firefox, mas quando envio para o servidor não funciona corretamente no Chrome. Testei outras formas como pode ser visto comentados, sempre o mesmo resultado.

Quando a página é recarregada o novo conteúdo que foi inserido não aprece, tendo que dar F5 mais uma vez para os dados aparecerem na tela, não estou carregando este conteúdo via ajax, ele é carregado via php normal na página. E como o conteúdo não carrega o formulário que deveria sumir, ainda fica ativo possibilitando o envio de mais documentos, mesmo que o envio de mais de um documentos esteja bloqueado este problema passa para o usuário que o doc não foi enviado. Já que a informação não aparece na tela.

Comment: O problema ocorre apenas no Chrome? Já testou pela navegação anônima?

Comment: Apenas no Chrome, já tentei anônima também, mesmo resultado. Estou suspeitando que pode ser do lado do servidor, pois local funciona perfeitamente. De todo modo vou abrir um chamado no server.

Comment: O reload não acontece apenas quando envio um pdf. :(

Comment: Nesses casos é muito importante acompanhar o console do navegador pra depurar o javascript e a resposta do servidor para ter uma noção mais clara do que pode estar acontecendo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por algum motivo que desconheço(se alguém souber), os headers do arquivo chamado não estavam sendo processados antes do redirecionamento, descobri isso enviado um arquivo maior e redirecionou normal. Então adicionei a seguinte linha que ainda precisa ser otimizada.

```js
setTimeout(function(){               
  location.reload(true);
}, 3000); //Tempo 3 segundos antes de redirecionar.
```

Answer (score 0):

É a melhor solução? NÃO. Mas pode tentar usar para teste:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Na minha opinião é uma maneira meio porca, mas para teste nos navegadores funciona.

Comment: Usei ela no lugar de `location.reload(true)`, da o mesmo resultado acima. O que deu certo foi usando o `setTimeout()` independente da forma que o redirecionamento está sendo feito..